# Elegant way to get around scoping issues with powershell jobs

Tags: powershell, closures, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, jobs

I have functions in separate files I need to run as jobs in one main file.

I need to be able to pass these functions arguments.

This is what I have:

testJobsMain.ps1:

```
$Functions = {
    . c:\.ps\func1.ps1
    . c:\.ps\func2.ps1
}

$arrOutput = @()
foreach($i in ('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee') ) {

    $ExecutionBlock = {
        FOO -myArg $i
        FOO2 -blah 'zzzzzzz'
    }

    $arrOutput += Start-Job -InitializationScript $Functions `
        -ScriptBlock $ExecutionBlock | 
            Wait-Job | Receive-Job
}

$arrOutput
```

func1.ps1

```
function FOO( $myArg ) { write-output $myArg }
```

func2.ps1

```
function FOO2( $blah ) { write-output $blah }
```

This is the output of testJobsMain.ps1:

```
PS> .\testjobsMain.ps1
zzzzzzz
zzzzzzz
zzzzzzz
zzzzzzz
```

It `$i` is not getting passed to the function. How can I do this?

Comment: Try replacing `FOO -myArg $i` with `FOO -myArg $using:i` and/or use `GetNewClosure()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass it as parameter like this

```
$ExecutionBlock = {
    param($passedI)
    FOO -myArg $passedI
    FOO2 -blah 'zzzzzzz'
}
$arrOutput += Start-Job -InitializationScript $Functions `
    -ScriptBlock $ExecutionBlock -ArgumentList $i | 
        Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

or use the `using` modifier (credits go to [Eris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2100227/eris)) like so

```
...
FOO -myArg $using:i
...
```

Comment: Is this the same as say javascript closures?

Comment: I get this error using that: `Start-Job : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ScriptBlock' because it is null`

Comment: Well I could not reproduce your issue with `null` but indeed my code didn't work as expected - sry for that. I updated my answer as it seems you will have to use parameters to pass the information to your job

Comment: Ok, is using a scriptblock param the equivalent of `$using:` or is one safer or faster? (for my specific use case). Because both seem to do what I want

Comment: No for your use case especially not as starting the job itself is by far the biggest workload of your script :) In general I don't think that there are big differences between both approaches (but I don't know it for sure) as the data has to be passed to job in some way anyway.  
I think `using` is a bit more concise and convenient but requires >= PowerShell 3.0